# Make mouse with busy icon (C#)

Tags: c#, mouse, busy-cursor

I have an application that takes a couple of seconds to run.
Is it possible to make the mouse with the busy icon while the app is processing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [Cursor.WaitCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors.waitcursor.aspx) property.

> You can use:
>
> ```
> Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
> ```
>
> and as long as there is some
>   processing going on in a `WinForms`
>   application, the cursor stays in the
>   `WaitCursor` state.
>
> You can as well use your custom
>   designed cursors:
>
> ```
> Cursor.Current = new Cursor("C:\\Cursors\\MyWait.cur");
> ```

source: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/238623-how-change-mouse-cursor-busy-state

Comment: The `UseWaitCursor` property is more reliable.

Comment: The `UseWaitCursor` property is not at all more reliable. For tasks that momentarily block the UI thread, the cursor won't change until after the task has completed and returned control to Windows.

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the form's [`UseWaitCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.usewaitcursor.aspx) property to `true`.  (And remember to set it to `false` again afterwords, preferably in a `finally` block)

You can also set [`Application.UseWaitCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.usewaitcursor.aspx) to `true` to apply it to every form.

Answer (score 2):

*I have no option to add my answer as a comment to SLaks answer, so i post it as an answer*

In order to force application to set cursor to wait cursor at once, you have to call for Application.DoEvents() method after setting Application.UseWaitCursor, **otherwise it might be changed after the lengthy process has been completed**

```
    Application.UseWaitCursor=true;
    Application.DoEvents();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

You will need a reference to System.Windows.Forms to change the cursor.